# okhttp log not printing

Tags: android, okhttp

I am building an api client using retrofit with this method:

```
private fun createNewApiClient(authRefreshClient: AuthRefreshClient,
                                   preferencesInteractor: PreferencesInteractor): ApiClient {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(PrettyLogger())
        loggingInterceptor.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE


        val okHttpClient = createHttpClientBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
           
                .baseUrl(Interactors.apiEndpoint)
                .build()
                .create(ApiClient::class.java)
    }
```

Debug is set to true in my generated BuildConfig file:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");

}
```

I can confirm that the call I am making with this client is being made because I put a lot statement in the throwable portion of RX's subscribe:

```
Interactors.api.apiClient.getUserByEmail(email).
                .subscribe({
                    Log.d("Email exists")
                   //Success
                }, {

        
             Log.e("Call is failing")
                     
                    }
                })
```

But the body of the request is not showing up in my log statements. Nothing from okhttp is showing up. What is wrong with my implemention of okhttp?

Comment: Are you sure, that in `BuildConfig` you have `true` value? Did you enter to this class after compiling?

Comment: This class is generated by the compilation process. I also removed the if statement and set the logging level to full in all cases and it still didn't work.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with this `PrettyLogger()`? Try to use `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger` from library.

Comment: That was the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `PrettyLogger()` with logger from `HttpLoggingInterceptor`

So replace yours:

```
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(PrettyLogger())
```

in to:

```
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
```